# How to draw on a transparent NSWindow with a transparent NSView?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nswindow, drawrect, nswindowcontroller

I want to draw on the screen with a transparent background, so that everything (e.g. open applications are still visible).

In windowDidLoad of my custom NSWindowController i have the follwing:

```
[self.window setOpaque: NO];
[self.window setHasShadow:NO];
[self.window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
[self.window setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
```

My custom NSWindow overrides canBecomeKeyWindow

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow {
   return YES;
}
```

My View overrides drawRect

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
  [[NSColor clearColor]set];
  NSRectFill(rect);
  ...
}
```

**Problem:** Trying to draw by using mouse events inside of my custom view results in the view/application beneath my Window to receive these events.

*It justs works when i do not set the NSWindow styleMask to NSBorderlessWindowMask or by setting the background color of the custom view to semitransparent.*

```
[[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.05] set]
```

**How can i draw on screen with full transparency and NSBorderlessWindowMask?**

Comment: Adding

    [self.window setIgnoresMouseEvents:NO];

to windowDidLoad of my custom NSWindowController solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
[self.window setIgnoresMouseEvents:NO];
```

to windowDidLoad of my custom NSWindowController solved it